# Is mail content sent from a https site secured automatically?

Tags: email, https

I have a mail form, the URL is `https://www.example.com/contact` for example. As you see, its https. The site contains some form fields and a send button. When the mail and the content is sent using PHP for example. will the content be secured as well?

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on the server side. If I understand your question correctly...

While you send email from your local machine to the server (i.e. a proxy between you and the receiver) in a secure way it doesn't mean that the proxy server will send it to the receiver the same way. And there is no way to check this (unless you've actually developed the proxy server). That being said every self-respecting server would do that.

Answer (score 0):

No.

HTTP will ensure that the communication between the browser and the HTTP server will be encrypted.

It will not cause the communication between the two SMTP servers to be encrypted.

In general, if you want secure email communication then you need to do so at the message level (e.g. by using PGP).